# UITableView Stretching Issue

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios5

I have a UIViewController that has an image and label at the top followed by a UITableView.  In the IB it looks perfect, but when I run the application in the simulator the UITableView is stretching and taking up the entire screen.

I've turned off all autosizing and set all of the values for stretching to 0, but it's still taking up the entire screen.  I even tried some advice I saw on another post which suggested putting the UITableView in a UIView that was sized, but that did not work either.

Any suggestions on how to stop the UITableView from resizing and filling the screen?  I am running XCode 4.2.1 with iOS5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give frame size to your tableView like this-

1) make your tableView's IBOutlet property in .h class, and synthesize in .m class.
2) connect it in Xib.
3) than in your .m class place this code in viewDidLoad-

```
tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 30.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f); // you can give any size to your table
```

Comment: @NainaSoni-- I Just ask coz of one reason.. I think you were working in rensoft 1 year ago ? ryt ?